# Importing external data with specific time format into MS Access

Tags: ms-access, date-format

I need to import data from a flat file to MS Access.  Part of the data is time information in the format HH:MM:SS.SSSS (i.e. 24-hour time, fractional seconds).  I have tried all of the standard time formats, and have monkeyed around with input masking, but Access keeps complaining that I am violating formats and won't import my data.  Anybody know how to do this?  Thanks.

(BTW, the "date-format" tag was the closest I could find to something like "time format".)

Comment: Bob did you tried to import that time information as text from flat file? is this file is CSV?

Comment: @AA.SC Yes.  I tried to import from a text flat file.  The fields are delimited by tabs.  I actually found on another site a comment from an MS engineer to the effect that MS Access time format simply doesn't allow fractional seconds.  So I put all the integers into the time and split off the fractional part of the seconds into a separate field.  Kind of ugly, but I haven't thought of a better way.  Ideas are appreciated!

Comment: It's true, the `Date/Time` column type in Access does not support fractional seconds. Do you need to keep that degree of precision or would rounding to the nearest second suffice?

Comment: One thing I've found is that when importing data from text files, Access uses roughly the first 100 rows of data to build up a preview of what it should expect from the entire file. If your first 100 rows contain all possible variations of the time column, that gives Access a better chance of reading it right.

Comment: @Gord Thompson  I don't need all the precision given but, no, rounding wouldn't be close enough.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the `Date/Time` column type in Access does not support fractional seconds. If you need to preserve the precision (and not round to the nearest second) then you'll need to import the time values as `Text` and then populate another `Long Integer` column with the times converted to tenths-of-milliseconds (which I have abbreviated to "tms"):

After the initial import of the times as `Text` you will have something like this

```
ID  hms_time       tms_time 
--  -------------  ---------
 1  00:00:00.0001
 2  23:59:59.9999
 3  00:00:00.0000
 4  03:25:45.6789
 5  22:57:40.0000
```

If you create a VBA function in an Access Module like this

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function Hms2Tms(hms As Variant) As Variant
    ' convert "hh:mm:ss.dddd" String
    '     to Long Integer tenths-of-milliseconds (0..863999999)
    Dim arr() As String, rtn As Long

    If IsNull(hms) Then
        Hms2Tms = Null
    Else
        arr = Split(hms, ":", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
        rtn = CLng(arr(0)) * 36000000 + CLng(arr(1)) * 600000
        arr = Split(arr(2), ".", 2, vbBinaryCompare)
        rtn = rtn + CLng(arr(0)) * 10000 + CLng(arr(1))
        Hms2Tms = rtn
    End If
End Function
```

then you can use the query

```sql
UPDATE TimesTable SET tms_time = Hms2Tms([hms_time])
```

to calculate the numeric equivalents

```
ID  hms_time       tms_time 
--  -------------  ---------
 1  00:00:00.0001          1
 2  23:59:59.9999  863999999
 3  00:00:00.0000          0
 4  03:25:45.6789  123456789
 5  22:57:40.0000  826600000
```

You can also use the following VBA function to convert a numeric "tms" time into an "hms" string:

```vbs
Public Function Tms2Hms(tms As Variant) As Variant
    ' convert Long Integer tenths-of-milliseconds (0..863999999)
    '     to "hh:mm:ss.dddd" String
    Dim hh As Long, mm As Long, ss_dddd As Currency, remainder As Long, rtn As String

    If IsNull(tms) Then
        Tms2Hms = Null
    Else
        hh = Int(CCur(tms) / 36000000)
        rtn = Format(hh, "00")
        remainder = tms - hh * 36000000
        mm = Int(CCur(remainder) / 600000)
        rtn = rtn & ":" & Format(mm, "00")
        remainder = remainder - mm * 600000
        ss_dddd = CCur(remainder) / 10000
        rtn = rtn & ":" & Format(ss_dddd, "00.0000")
        Tms2Hms = rtn
    End If
End Function
```